# Convolutional Neural Network in PyTorch with custom data

Tags: pytorch

I am trying create a CNN for classification of three dancers with skeleton data in PyTorch.
The Dataset is split into 3000 pieces each with 50 frames and 72 joint position data.
I want to interpret the data like an image and therefore want to use a CNN for classification, but I am not sure how to use the Dataloader. In this [link](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/cifar10_tutorial.html) there is an example on how to train a CNN for classification, but the Dataloader uses a pre-configured dataset and I am not sure how I should format my custom data in the argument "trainset" in the command:

```
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=batch_size,shuffle=False, num_workers=1)
```

My input data basically has 3000 data points each which has 50 frames of 72 joint positions.
And my labels are a vector of length 3000 each which can assume the output 0,1,2 for three different dancers.
I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an class that inherits `torch.utils.data.Dataset`. In short, the class needs to contain an `__init__` function that specifies necessary attributes, an `__getitem__` function that returns a data point (optionally with its label) at an indexed position, and a `__len__` function to specify the number of data points in your dataset.

Here is a template of how to create a customized dataset.

```
from torch.utils import data
class MyDataset(data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.dset = # load your data from the root here
    
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.dset[index]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.dset)
```

You may also like to refer to this real [implementation](https://github.com/a514514772/DISE-Domain-Invariant-Structure-Extraction/blob/master/util/loader/GTA5Loader.py), where I customize a dataset that uses GTA5 images for a semantic segmentation task.

Lastly, just treat it as a pre-configured dataset. For example,

```
trainset = MyDataset(root)
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False, num_workers=1)
```